# Convert a List of Lists into a dictionary? in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I Want to convert a list of lists into a dictionary where every sub-list are the key value in the dictionary
for example

```
array = [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]
```

I want to be output like this

```
dict = { a:b,c:d,e:f }
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> array = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
>>> dict(array)
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).
Arrays are called lists in Python, so rename your variable (`lst` is too generic, use a more specific name).
Remember to quote the strings.

```
lst = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
dct = {x[0]: x[1] for x in lst}
print(dct)
# {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}
```